# How can i add .pdf extention on the default upload files

Tags: 7, files, entities

When i create an article i saw that i'm allowed to upload image files only

> Allowed file types: .png .gif .jpg .jpeg

How can i add `.pdf` file extension and attached with the article?

I'm using zen theme

Comment: Try to create one field type "file"and then search the field "Allowed file extensions" and adding .pdf .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Structure > Content types, click manage fields for the article content type, then edit on the Image field. There you can edit the allowed file types.

**However**, note that this is an image field. It does not make sense to upload PDF files to an image type field. Instead, you might want to add a new field with type file and configure that to allow pdf files.

Also note that you can't leave the allowed values empty, that would not allow any file types.

Comment: it has nothing in managed field.Do I have to create new field?
How do I add vtt type in simple file upload ... I am using form to upload it works for txt but not working for vtt and exel

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for Drupal 6: [File attachment utilities](http://drupal.org/project/attachments); you can get some idea from its code.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Administer -> Site Configuration -> File Uploads," add '.pdf' to the "Default permitted file extensions:" section, and click on "Save configuration."

Comment: The queston is tagged [tag:7]. The setting you suggest is used doesn't exist in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can setting by content types -> article -> edit and then you must adding to upload field the extension .pdf

It' s easy!

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to *Administration » Structure » Content types*. Click on *Manage fields* for the "Article" content type.  Note that in Drupal 7, the default "Article" content type already have a field for file attachments (named "Attachment"), so there is no need to create a *new* field, as suggested in the currently accepted answer.

Press the *Edit* link on the *Attachment* field and locate the field *Allowed file extensions*

The default attachment content type is just `txt`.  Change this to `txt pdf`, and press "Save settings".

To add a PDF attachement, make sure you use the *Attachment* field (not *Image* field) for the PDF-attachment when creating new Article content.